# Reciprocal of a Derivative

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

If g(x) is a continuously differentiable function then what is the solution to the ode
$$
f'(x)= \frac{1}{g'(x)}?
$$

Comment: There is no simple relation to be found here apart from the obvious $f(x) = \int\frac{{\rm d}x}{g'(x)}$. The integral $\int\frac{{\rm d}x}{g'(x)}$ cannot be simplified without explicitly knowing $g$.

Comment: $g(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)$.

Comment: @xpaul No. Take for instance $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=\log(\sqrt x)$.